# why does union all not de-duplicate adequately?

Tags: duplicates, ssms, union

I have 28 fixed width files that I break up and import into SQL. For sake of ease, I will call them industry1 to industry28. From an examination of the whole in excel, I find that there are 1257 duplicates of 38,700 total rows. The duplicates will appear in somewhat random fashion.

The table, industry, has 28 fields of which there is a composite primary key of 9 fields. The duplicates are of the entire row (all 28 fields).

When I try to use UNION ALL (example below), it only removes 28 duplicates. Can someone explain why this is the case?

```
 Select field1, field2...from industry1
 UNION ALL
 Select field1, field2...from industry2
 UNION ALL
 Select field1, field2...from industry3
 ... and so on
```

Comment: In [SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) `UNION ALL` explicitly isn't supposd to remove duplicates. I think you are not seeing any duplicates removed. Compare with same query using `UNION`.

Comment: I ran the same query with UNION and it removed about 160.

Comment: I am guessing the way you determine duplicates and the way SQL loaded / determined duplicates make them not identical to SQL.

Comment: To determine a duplicate, I combine all 28 fields into one in excel using concatenate. From there, I use conditional formatting or remove duplicates to come to the 1257 mentioned before.

Comment: I would suggest using Gnu text tools or something similar to concatenate the 28 files in text format and find duplicate lines. How did you break the files into fields before putting in Excel? Are the files all identical in width / column format?

Comment: initially, i was using excel but recently have figured out how to use bulk insert to break up and import each of the 28 files. Yes, they are 139 characters broken into 22 separate fields.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UNION` and not `UNION ALL` if you are looking to eliminate duplicate rows from your query. `UNION` essentially gives you the `DISTINCT` result set and if you don't mind duplicates or want slightly faster execution speed then `UNION ALL` would be a better option.

From Google:

> UNION ALL command is equal to UNION command, except that UNION ALL selects all the values. The difference between Union and Union all is that Union all will not eliminate duplicate rows, instead it just pulls all the rows from all the tables fitting your query specifics and combines them into a table.